# Is it possible to implement socket.io connection in express route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I implement a payment service which depend on one of my express route as a callback route, so whenever a user want to make a payment, they will be redirected to this payment service link which  entirely different my backend/frontend domain. After a successful payment, user will then be redirected to my express `GET` route (callback route), in this route is where I give users their asset and then redirect them to the frontend.

`EXPECTATION`
My expectation is, whenever a user make a purchase, I want a real time update on the frontend for others to see some details about the purchase without refreshing their browser.

`WHAT I'VE TRIED`
I had think socket.io would solve this, like adding a socket connection in the route to then push the data to the frontend. But after making lot of research, no solution seems to work for me.

`HERE IS A SIMPLE CODE OF WHAT I'VE TRIED`

=============================== server.js ========================

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const http = require("http")
const cors = require("cors")
const session = require("express-session")
const runSocket = require("./runSocket")
const { Server } = require("socket.io")

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

const server = http.createServer(app)

server.listen(3004, () => {
  console.log("SERVER IS RUNNING")
})
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
})


const postRoute = require("./routes/postData")(io)

app.use("/post-data", postRoute)
```

==================================== postData Route ======================================

```
module.exports = function (io) {
  router.post("/", async (req, res) => { 
    const data = req?.body?.data.message
    const room = req?.body?.data?.room

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log("Socket Running...")
      socket.to(room).emit("the_message", data)
    })

    console.log("Under socket...")
    return res.status(200).json({ data: req.body.data })
  })

  return router
}
```

This log: in postData route is not printing `console.log("Socket Running...")`

`EXPECTATION`
My expectation is, whenever a user make a purchase, I would like to make a real time update on the frontend for others to see some details about the purchase.

UPDATE: The Payment Gateway config looks somthing like this:

```
 const { body } = await got.post("https://payment-provider-link", {
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer token for payment" },
    json: {
      email: "email@gmail.com",
      amount: amount * 100,
      initiate_type: "inline",
      callback_url: `${BackendBaseUrl}/payment-callback`, // <<<============
    },
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you don't need the io.on("connection") in ur route. Remove that piece of code and simply change it to io.to(room).emit("the_message", data). Also make sure to have the other sockets joined the room ur trying to emit to otherwise they won't receive the data.